# Trigger for updating insert content

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm building a trigger to act before insert to do two things :
 - reject given values (works)
- update null values (can't get it to work)

the table of trigger looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE peeps(
  name VARCHAR(20),
  surname VARCHAR(20)
);
```

While the trigger itself looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER name_a_i
BEFORE INSERT ON krasnoludki FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN

    IF initcap(:new.name) LIKE 'Adrian%' THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Name starting with Adrian is prohibited');          
    ELSE

      IF :new.name = '' OR :new.name IS NULL THEN
        SELECT count(*) INTO v_count
        FROM peeps
        WHERE initcap(name) LIKE 'No_%';

        UPDATE peeps
        SET name = concat('No_', v_count + 1)
        WHERE name = :new.name;
      END IF;

    END IF;
  END name_a_i;
```

Everything compiles but when i put null value as a name it doesn't update null value to No_%.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

It's Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since :NEW.name is NULL, this update

```
Update peeps set name = concat('No_',v_count+1) where name = :NEW.name;
```

will not work because name = :NEW.name will not work.

You need to change your logic.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select count(*) into v_count from peeps where initcap(name) like 'No_%';
:NEW.name := concat('No_',v_count);
Update peeps set name = concat('No_',v_count+1) where name = :NEW.name;
```

this will update the name and table as well.

Comment: Yup this is it, thank you so much, but if you could explain to me logic behind this as i want to know how it function not only how does it.

So the :NEW.name is a pointer and till end of trigger i can shuffle it's value as i want?